# Error when deploying GAE Java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform

Been using Google App Engine for a while and I am now trying to deploy my application that usually works like a charm, but now I'm getting this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appengineDeploy'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appengineDeploy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 103 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy(CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:88)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.DeployTask.deployAction(DeployTask.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        ... 115 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.handleProcess(LegacyProcessHandler.java:87)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.GcloudRunner.run(GcloudRunner.java:98)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy(CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:86)
        ... 117 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:28)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.syncRun(LegacyProcessHandler.java:144)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.handleProcess(LegacyProcessHandler.java:83)
        ... 119 more

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3m 9s
8 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

The app is written in Java using Gradle 4.4.1 (Groovy 2.4.12) and when I'm doing gcloud app deploy for my Node applications it works. It's just this Java app (gcloud appengineDeploy).

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    ext {
        springVersion = '4.3.12.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.1.RELEASE'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

jar {
    baseName = '***thename***'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
    //providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'

    // tag::jetty[]
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]

    // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'

    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-storage', version: '1.14.0'

    compile("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1")
    compile("javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
bootRun {
    addResources = true

    //ENABLE FOR DEBUGGING
    //jvmArgs = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=y']
}
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
    projectId = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
    // it used to be like this: project = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
  }
}
group = 'se.theId***'   // Generated output GroupId
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'          // Version in generated output
eclipse {
    project.natures 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.5'
}
```

UPDATE 190201:

Pastebin of recent try: https://pastebin.com/A2LNgssh

Comment: I understand that you are deploying using the `gradle appengineDeploy` command. Can you share your `build.gradle` file? What version of gradle are you using? (you can check it running `gradle --version) - As well, are you able to run the application locally, using the `gradle appengineRun` command?

Comment: I updated the question with build.gradle. Gradle 4.4.1 (Groovy 2.4.12). I cant run the gradle appengineRun: `not found in root project 'api'.`

Comment: Can you try to directly specify the version of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin` instead of using an env variable? 
Also I tried in my side your gradle script, added some modifications and it seemed to work: https://pastebin.com/beBLJm92 (note that there are dependencies there that are needed for my application, you might have to remove them)

Comment: How do you mean 'specify the version of the spring framework'? I'm very new to this (did not config or set up this myself). I'll try to modify and use your script. Thanks.

Comment: You can change the version on the line `classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:VERSION_NUMBER")`. As well, may I ask where did you get this config? If it's some sort of tutorial I can try it on my side so I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time Joan, but the issue seems to have been resolved by itself. I posted an answer. Might have had to do with Java version, but I am very unsure.

Comment: This is so strange. I've been trying to deploy now for the past hour with no good result. Same issue again! And I haven't changed anything in the configs. So weird, since it worked two days ago. I'm starting to think this is on Google's end.

Comment: I just updated my answer with my latest try in Pastebin.

Comment: Updated my answer with what I believe to be the real fix.

Answer (score 1):

I tried today, changed nothing, and it worked. It says I updated Java 4 days ago when I check but I have no memory of that. Perhaps it was done automatically but as far as I know I installed 191 update manually (which is what I still have).

Maybe the issue was at Googles side.

UPDATE 190201:

OK, so I finally found out the problem! I think. I just cant wrap my head around how it could work earlier. But my application uses a database which it tries to connect to using credentials stated in the application. I did not set this gradle project up, and apparently the guy who did stated the credentials in two other files (application.yaml x2). This was being used by GAE while deploying, and since we've changed these credentials recently, this made the deployment fail.

I could read this from further loggin using --stacktrace and --debug while deploying.

Comment: This is so strange. I've been trying to deploy now for the past hour with no good result. Same issue again! And I haven't changed anything in the configs. So weird, since it worked two days ago. I'm starting to think this is on Google's end.

Comment: I just updated my answer with my latest try in Pastebin.

Comment: Updated my answer with what I believe to be the real fix.